# IONIZE CMS post installation problem

Tags: codeigniter

I decided to try Ionize cms which is build over CodeIgnitor. I have my apache, php , mysql installed seperately. When I finished installing the cms successfully, I cannot access the website. Some weird errors occurs like

```
Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in ... \ionize-0.9\application\models\article_model.php on line 224
```

I got frustated and searched many places. Later I tested the CMS in WAMP, and there it worked.

Now I have no idea, what is going on, everything the CMS needs to run, is tested during the installation. I dont have any idea.... how to solve it. Please help me

Comment: Robin, I have updated this as an issue in their github. Here is a [link](https://github.com/ionize/ionize/issues/17) if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 1):

For one unknown reason, all the tables of the database weren't installed. Ionize currently doesn't check that situation. If it works on one server (Wamp) and not on one other (manually LAMP installed server), compare the tables list on each system.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue on a WAMP server and the reason was that it couldn't created the article_type table.
I'd suggest checking your database to see if that table exist.

If it doesn't take a look at the data.sql file and try to run only that create table section. It should spit out an error. In my case the description text NOT NULL default "" was throwing an error (BLOB/TEXT column 'description can't have a default value).

I fixed it by making sure description doesn't have a default value.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS article_type (
  id_type int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  type varchar(50) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  ordering int(11) default 0,
  description text NOT NULL,
  type_flag TINYINT( 1 ) NOT NULL default 0,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id_type)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 COMMENT='0.9.7';
```